# What to do with extra rare/set/legendary items in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I started playing on Torment difficulty and I'm gathering a lot of rare/set/legendary items that I don't know what to do with since my gear is better. I'm unsure if I should sell or break down the items into crafting materials. I just got the Kanai cube, but I'm not sure if I should extract the attributes of my legendary items or just break them down for mats. Is it better to keep them for other characters? I seem to only be gathering items with +Str and +Vit that could be good for my Crusader, but nothing I can transfer to my Wizard.

So basically, what should I do with all this extra loot?

Comment: To be honest, after level 70, when you start earning Paragon points, Rare (yellow) gear is useless.

Comment: You will ALWAYS need crafting materials, especially post-70. Even the white stuff. Stock up, friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rares should be salvaged, always.  They're completely useless once you fill every slot with a legendary item.  You'll need the materials you get form scrapping rares (and also white/blues) in almost every recipe.

For the majority of the legendaries you find, their best use is to either extract their power using kanai's cube, or break it down into a forgotten soul.  The one caveat is that it worth it to save any ancient gear you find just in case it comes in handy down the line.  Ancient legendaries are rare enough that they're worth keeping.

For extra set pieces, there are ways you can use the kanai's cube to reroll it into another piece in the set.  (10 souls, 10 dbs).  This allows you to complete sets much faster.

Finally, there's almost no way to transfer useful gear between classes.  Unless the item rolls near perfectly and you can reroll the main stat (say from str to int), or you can reroll it so it doesn't have a main stat, it won't be as useful as any legendary found on the wizard.

Even between same main stat classes, they typically use drastically different gear you won't be switching much other than a ring or two.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Will I know if the legendary is ancient? Is it going to be in the name or something?

Comment: @jgadoury yea it will have a very visible gold box around the item, see example here : http://www.diablowiki.net/Ancient_items

Comment: I would also add, that if playing hardcore, it is worth saving duplicate legendary pieces in case your character dies  That way if you ever create a new character of the same class it will be waiting for them when they reach 70.

Answer (score 1):

There is much to do with duplicate legendaries. The Law of Kulle is a recipe for Kanai's cube that allows you to reroll the stats of a legendary item, so it's in your best interest to maintain a duplicate set of your gear to reroll when needed. Also, certain legendaries are universally useful, and keeping a few copies around to reroll can help. 
You should hold onto at least a pair of :

1. Focus
2. Restraint
3. Endless walk
4. Compass rose
5. Convection of elements
6. Obsidian ring of the Zodiac
7. Warzechian Armguards
8. Nemesis Bracers
9. (Maybe) Litany of the Undaunted & the wailing host
10. Avarice band

These are legendaries that are commonly called for in builds, (the bracers in particular are in literally every speed running build) and having them on hand, even if the stats aren't perfect, gives you a major leg up whilst transitioning gear.

NEVER EVER EVER disenchant or throw out either a Puzzle Ring nor a Bovine Bardiche, as they can be placed in the cube to open a portal to bonus levels.

You can also strip the legendary powers of most legendaries by putting them in the cube, allowing you to use them without having the item equipped.

Rares? Rares are trash. Salvage them, or, one you have 10k crafting mats, sell them.